# How many Russian politicians send their own children to the war in Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, conscription

Today Russian President Vladimir Putin declared a "[partial mobilisation](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-62988475)", hoping to add 300,000 more soldiers to the war in Ukraine.  This follows the success of Ukraine's counter-offensive, reclaiming much land around Kharkiv.  The exact number of Russian deaths is unknown, with estimates varying from around 6,000 (Russia) to 25,000 (USA), to 55,000 (Ukraine).  At any rate, things apparently aren't going to plan for the Kremlin.

It has been noted that Russia's poorest regions and ethnicities have suffered [disproportionate causalities](https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-ukraine-war-women-soldiers-home-buryatia-tyva/31940262.html).  Which makes me wonder, are any of Russia's pro-war politicians willing to send their own children into battle?

1. How many Russian politicians have children serving in the armed forces?
2. Of those, how many of these politicians are pro-Putin, and how many of their children have fought in Ukraine?
3. A useful comparison may be with another nation, such as the USA's House of Representatives/Senate and deployments in Afghanistan/Iraq.

**Edit:** To clarify and reduce scope, we can limit 'politicians' to refer to members of the Duma.  Part of what provoked this question was a [video of a town hall meeting](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-news/2022/03/07/anti-war-protests-russian-mothers-putin-sons-cannon-fodder/) with a regional governor in March.  Sergey Tsivilev (governor of Kuzbass, Siberia) was trying to calm the families of conscripts who hadn't heard anything from their sons.  One irate mother asked: "where is your son, by the way?" to which he said: "my son is studying at university."

**In response to some downvotes and close votes: seems a fair question to ask**, as much as pointing out how many [American politicians dodged the draft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_evasion_in_the_Vietnam_War#Politicians) in the Vietnam War (Bush Jr, Dick Cheney, Bill Clinton, Mitt Romney, Bernie Sanders, Donald Trump, Joe Biden, etc).

Comment: Dmitry Peskov will not: https://www.google.com/amp/s/meduza.io/amp/feature/2022/09/21/soratniki-navalnogo-pozvonili-synu-peskova-i-poprosili-yavitsya-v-voenkomat-tot-otvetil-chto-budet-reshat-etot-vopros-na-drugom-urovne

Comment: An answer would not be incredibly illuminating unless we had a (numerical) point of comparison. "Politician" is also a rather broad category... from the local councilman level etc. I doubt you can find such stats computed for any war-country combo. Maybe limit the Q to national parliamentarians (Duma). I could find in a pinch something like that about US in Iraq https://joewilson.house.gov/media-center/articles/associated-press-half-a-dozen-lawmakers-have-kids-at-war

Comment: No fan of Russia.  But this Q is entirely too specific in asking solely about Russian politicians on a subject broadly known to be an issue in many places.  i.e. it seems entirely calculated to discredit.  VTC.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6372).

Comment: The latest edit to this question changed what the question was asking and thereby invalidated the existing answer. I rolled it back. If you have a followup question, please post it as a new question.

Comment: It's an interesting question but I agree with the others who feel your pointed questions are not suitable here - whether a politician has a relative serving in the military or a school or is homeless, for example, is irrelevant to this SE as it has nothing to do with *"governments, policies and political processes"*.

Comment: I agree, both "Russian" and "Ukrainian" varieties should I think be closed

Answer (score 1):

Acording to russian sorces the head of the Crimea said that his son was drafted into the army as part of a partial mobilization as can be read in [this article](https://rg.ru/2022/09/23/reg-ufo/sergej-aksenov-soobshchil-o-prizyve-syna-po-chastichnoj-mobilizacii.html?ysclid=l8eej5pind32037320):

> **Sergey Aksenov announced his son's call for partial mobilization**
>
> The son of the head of Crimea was drafted into the Armed Forces of the
> Russian Federation as part of a partial mobilization. This was
> announced by Sergey Aksenov.
>
> "The law is the same for everyone. Today my son was drafted and has
> already left for the unit on the territory of the unit," TASS quotes
> the head of the RK.
>
> Sergey Aksenov stressed that he is proud of his son, who believes that
> it is impossible to stay away from the events taking place, and he
> must pay his debt to the motherland, although he has already served in
> the army.
>
> It is known that the politician has two children - a daughter Kristina
> born in 1994 and a 25-year-old son Oleg.

Also some Duma members have expressed their wil to join the Special Military Operation, as can be read in [this russian article](https://argumenti.ru/politics/2022/09/790826):

> **State Duma deputies Milonov, Sablin, Khubezov and Sokol asked to send them to the special operation zone in Ukraine**
>
> Deputies of the lower house of the Russian parliament Vitaly Milonov,
> Dmitry Sablin, Dmitry Khubezov and Sergey Sokol asked to be sent to
> the special operation zone in Ukraine. This, as RIA Novosti reports,
> was told by Andrey Turchak, First Deputy Chairman of the Federation
> Council.
>
> "Turchak said that he had received statements from the first four
> deputies of the State Duma with a request to send them to the special
> operation zone. Among the applicants are Vitaly Milonov, Dmitry
> Sablin, Dmitry Khubezov and Sergey Sokol," the publication says, which
> appeared in the Telegram channel of the domestic news agency.
>
> As it was reported earlier on Friday, the speaker of the Federation
> Council Valentina Matvienko noted that the ruling regime in Ukraine
> has already become terrorist in its essence.

Also Kadyrov has said he is going to send his children to fight in Ukraine as can be read in [this article](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/5593731):

> **Kadyrov said he would send his minor children to the front line in Ukrai**ne
>
> The head of Chechnya Ramzan Kadyrov said that his minor children
> Ahmad, Eli and Adam will soon take part in a military operation in
> Ukraine. According to him, they "will be on the most difficult
> sections of the contact line."
>
> Kadyrov said that his three minor sons will soon "go to the front line
> and will be on the most difficult sections of the contact line."
>
> "I appeal to the empty—mouthed people who claimed that my loved ones
> do not take part in their own: in the near future you will have the
> opportunity to take positions with the guys and personally make sure
> that Akhmat is a FORCE!", — Mr. Kadyrov wrote.
>
> "Akhmat, Eli and Adam are ready to apply their skills in the SVO zone.
> And I'm not kidding. It's time to show yourself in a real fight, and I
> only welcome their desire. Soon they will go to the front line and
> will be on the most difficult sections of the contact line," Ramzan
> Kadyrov wrote in his Telegram channel.
>
> As Ramzan Kadyrov writes, his sons Akhmat, Eli and Adam have been
> undergoing military training "almost from an early age." He recalled
> that Akhmat is 16 years old, Eli is 15 years old, Adam is 14 years
> old.

Comment: "some Duma members have expressed their wil" this part doesn't seem to answer the question at all. Duma members are surely kind of top Russian politician, but the question is not about them but about their children, I think.

Comment: @Trilarion At least the first part is about a son of polititian.

Comment: Why does it have to be about children? The people being mobilized now are mostly grown-ups. Framing them as "someone's children" is disingenous. Many of them have children of their own.

Comment: @alamar because it's a question of whether or not personal connections to politicians are used to get out of service which is proclaimed to be a responsibility of every citizen.  In other words, it's a question about whether there is nepotism and corruption are present in this particular aspect of public life.